# How to avoid battery drainage if the app is using GPS even when the app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, core-data, geolocation

I have to build an app that will have the following features :-

1. A way to add users and their data in a database. (which will be parse)
2. The app will access the location updates of the user (say after every 10 minutes or when the user has moved a significant distance). This will be done even when the app is in background. These locations will then be updated to the parse database as and when the new locations are received.

I am a beginner, so any suggestion to how i should approach this will be appreciated. Most importantly, i have the following problems :-

1. The app will also run in the background and will regularly use GPS. This will drain a lot of battery. How can i avoid this? (The precision of the locations are important)
2. The app will regularly update these locations to the parse database and will have to make regular API requests which will add to the cost. How can i minimise this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description what you want is "significant location change" monitoring, which is built in to `CLLocationManager`. Instead of running continuous location updates, you tell the location manager to send you "significant" changes in location, i.e. when the user has moved some undocumented "significant" amount. It's specifically designed to minimize battery drain, so you don't need to bother disabling and reenabling it. Instead iOS makes sure you're using as little battery as possible to get the updates.

The `CLLocationManager` discuss the approach in some detail, but the basics are:

- Once you've created your location manager, tell it to start significant location updates:

  ```
  locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
  ```
- Location changes are provided to the delegate via the same `locationManager(manager:didUpdateLocations:)` method used for continuous location updates.
- iOS will wake your app up to let it process location updates.

Comment: As far as i know, this method takes does not uses GPS but uses cell towers. How accurate will the locations be if i use this method?

Comment: "Less accurate than GPS" is all I can really say. But also with much less effect on the battery and much less complexity in your code. In some informal experiments it seems to be very accurate, at least within a city.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to periodically update your location rather than leave GPS on continuously. [Here's a tutorial covering `CLLocationManager`](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/) you may find helpful.

Without specific code, I can't give you a specific answer, but generally speaking you'll want to periodically turn on `CLLocationManager`, get your location, and turn it off again until the next update. You can also configure the accuracy of `CLLocationManager`--the more specific your location, the more battery power is required.

[Here's another tutorial on CLLocationManager](http://www.devfright.com/how-to-use-the-clregion-class-for-geofencing/) to take a peek at, too.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the prompt reply. Yes i will use CLLocationManager and turn it off whenever i get an accurate location fix.But the app needs to update the new locations very frequently. Also, the app will save the locations on the database and display it on the phone simultaneously.Which database do you think will work better? parse or firebase? I guess firebase's real-time capabilities will be a huge help?

Comment: I haven't used firebase or parse, but I have used Core Data.

Comment: Core Data will not be very useful if i have to make this location data accessible to the other users. right?

Comment: In terms of sharing with other users, I don't think so. I'll need to read up on the DBs you mentioned. I see Parse mentioned a lot on here--I'd wager there's probably more code floating around with more mentions, but being unfamiliar with Parse, so I'm not sure if it would suit your needs better.

Comment: alright.if you do find anything helpful on databases, do tell.I will read the parse and firebase documentation too.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your question dealt with `CLLocation` usage and how to minimize it. If I answered your question, please click the checkmark.